# How can I use WebStorm to create a Cucumber step definition file in TypeScript instead of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumber, webstorm, cucumberjs

I'm building a new e2e test suite using Cucumber.js and I'd like to use TypeScript for my step files. When I create a new step and I press `Alt+Enter` to have WebStorm generate a new step file the only option I am presented with is to create a JavaScript file.[image]

Does anyone know how I can make this create a new step file in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webstorm doesn't seem to provide a wizard for file type "TypeScript" so you might want to create your step definition file manually.

For the [Simple Math Example](http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-js/) a possible TS step definition file might look like this:

```
import * as cucumber from "cucumber";

module.exports = function () {
    // Assign this to a typed variable so we have type-safe access
    let sd: cucumber.StepDefinitions = this;

    // The common variable is simply kept in function scope here
    let variable: number = 0;

    sd.Given(/^a variable set to (\d+)$/, (value: string) => {
        variable = parseInt(value);
    });

    sd.When(/^I increment the variable by (\d+)$/, (value: string) => {
        variable += parseInt(value);
    });

    sd.Then(/^the variable should contain (\d+)$/, (value: string) => {
        if (variable != parseInt(value))
            throw new Error('Variable should contain '+value
                          + ' but it contains ' + variable + '.');
    });
};
```

Put this content in e.g. features/step_definitions/mathSteps.ts and paste the feature code from [the example](http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-js/) into a file called e.g. features/math.feature and you should have a running example.

Comment: I'm selecting this answer for just the `Webstorm doesn't seem to provide a wizard for file type "TypeScript"` section. That's pretty much what I was looking to know. Thanks!

Comment: i wasn't able to access anything through cucumber.StepDefinitions. Error: `StepDefinitions` does not exist on type 'typeof path/to/my/cucumber/@types/index.ts'