# "Undefined step reference" in WebStorm while trying refer to TypeScript step definition code

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumber, webstorm, gherkin

While implementing a few test scripts based on cucumber-protractor-typescript logic, I ran into a problem: my Gherkin can not find declaration of the steps:

[image: can not find declaration of steps]

Steps definition is coded with TypeScript. However, all my tests compiles and runs successfully.
[There is the same problem as mine, but it didn't solve my problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698154/how-can-i-use-webstorm-to-create-a-cucumber-step-definition-file-in-typescript-i)

When I am trying to create step definition file manually, there is no option to create TypeScript file, only JavaScript:

[image: When I am trying to create step definition file manually, there is no option to create TypeScript file, only JavaScript]

Here is my example of step definition:

```
defineSupportCode(({Given, When, Then, Before}) => {
      let search: Search;

   Before(() => {
       search = new Search();
   });

   Given(/^User on the angular site$/, async () => {
       let title = await browser.getTitle();
       return expect(title).to.equal('Angular');
   });

   When(/^User type "(.*?)" into the search input field$/, async (text: string) => {
       await search.enterSearchInput(text);
   });

   Then(/^User should see some results in the search overlay$/, async () => {
       await search.getSearchResultItems();
       let count = await search.getCountOfResults();
       return expect(count).to.be.above(0);
   });
});
```

And my cucumber file:

```
 Feature: Search
   As a developer using Angular
   User need to look-up classes and guidelines
   So that User can concentrate on building awesome apps

 @SearchScenario
   Scenario: Type in a search-term
   Given User on the angular site
   When User type "foo" into the search input field
   Then User should see some results in the search overlay
```

My repositories structure:

```
/features
   /steps
    searchSteps.ts
 search.feature
/pages
 search.ts
```

Does somebody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately WebStorm provides not support for writing Cucumber.js tests in TypeScript. Please vote for [WEB-22516](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22516) and [WEB-29665](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29665) to be notified on any progress with TypeScript support